# How to print an array of strings

Tags: c

I am trying to print an array of strings. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array (char * strings[]) {
    size_t array_length = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]);
    for (int i=0; i < array_length; i++)
        printf("%s, ", strings[i]);
}

int main(void) {

    char * strings[] = {
        "Hello",
        "Zerotom",
        "new"
    };

    // it does work here...
    printf("Array size: %lu\n", sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]));

    // but not here
    print_array(strings);

    return 0;
}
```

From this, I get a warning that says:

> strings.c:4:30: warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of
>         'char **' instead of 'char *[]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
>           size_t array_length = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]);

However, if I change the function arg from `char * strings[]` to `char **`, it returns the wrong length (1 instead of 3). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `void print_array (char **strings)` and you must pass the `number` of strings to the function (or use a sentinel `NULL` to mark the end of valid strings) `size_t array_length = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]);` does NOT work after the array is passed as a parameter to a function (it is converted to a pointer) so you in effect have ``size_t array_length = sizeof(a_pointer) / sizeof(a_char);``

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin why does it work "within the initial function" but when its passed to another function you cannot get the array length?

Comment: On access an array is converted to a pointer to the first element (passing as a parameter counts as an access). There are 4-exceptions when an array is not converted to a pointer, one of which is when used with the `sizeof` operator (but that must be within the scope in which the array was declared). After being passed as a parameter, it is just a pointer. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: "it", `string`, is not the same in the 2 cases,  With `char * strings[]`, `strings` is not an array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- thanks, when using a sentinel value, I assume in that case all arrays are then "length - 1" ?

Comment: You just add the final element, e.g. `..., "new", NULL`. Then you can pass `strings` to the function and do `while (*strings != NULL) printf("%s, ", *strings++);` or `size_t i = 0; while (strings[i] != NULL) printf("%s, ", strings[i++]);` Or, if you prefer `for` loops then `for (size_t i = 0; strings[i]; i++) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can print `strings` in `main()` but not in `print_array` is the result of how an array is converted to a pointer on access. What this means is that when you access an array (subject to 4 exceptions below) the array is converted to a pointer to the first element in the array. After the conversion takes place, as it does when you pass an array as a parameter to a function, you have only a pointer, not an array.

The C11 Standard (as well as the C17 Standard) reads as follows:

**Array pointer conversion**

(p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. 
[C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

If you note above, when used with the `sizeof` operator, and array is not converted to a pointer, so in `main()`,  `sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0])` provides the number of elements in the array of string. However, after you pass `strings` to `print_array`, the conversion to pointer has already occurred, so that in `print_array` your attempted use of `sizeof` results in:

```
size_t array_length = sizeof(a_pointer) / sizeof(a_char);
```

(which is `8` on x86_64, or `4` on x86)

You have two choices **(1)** pass the number of elements in your array as a second parameter to `print_array`, or **(2)** make the last pointers in `strings` `NULL` (to be used as a sentinel value). Then in `print_array` you can just iterate over `strings[i]` until it is `NULL`.

A couple of quick examples:

**Passing the Number of Elements**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array (char **strings, size_t nptrs)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nptrs; i++)
        printf("%s, ", strings[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main(void) {

    char *strings[] = { "Hello",
                        "Zerotom",
                        "new" };

    print_array (strings, sizeof strings/sizeof *strings);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/prnarray
Hello, Zerotom, new,
```

**Adding a Sentinel `NULL` to `strings`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array (char **strings)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; strings[i]; i++)
        printf("%s, ", strings[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main(void) {

    char *strings[] = { "Hello",
                        "Zerotom",
                        "new",
                        NULL };        /* sentinel NULL */

    print_array (strings);

    return 0;
}
```

(same output)

There are at least a handful of ways to loop using either `for` or `while` loops and either using a pointer to `strings` and pointer arithmetic, or using array indexing (the difference are simple semantics as you are doing the same thing). Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.